# Disk configuration options, what can affect performance

Tags: drivers, configuration, performance, disk, parameter

I have 2 disks, the same model and vendor, first one , probably performs faster. We do write into multiple files.
Can you compare 2 configurations and tell what can affect performance?
 1. (faster)

```
*-storage
            description: RAID bus controller
            product: Smart Array G6 controllers
            vendor: Hewlett-Packard Company
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: scsi3
            version: 01
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom
            configuration: driver=hpsa latency=0
            resources: irq:40 memory:f3e00000-f3ffffff memory:f3df0000-f3df0fff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f0400000-f047ffff(prefetchable)
          *-generic UNCLAIMED
               description: SCSI
               product: P410i
               vendor: HP
               physical id: 3.0.0
               bus info: scsi@3:3.0.0
               version: 5.12
               serial: 500143801031E8B0
               configuration: ansiversion=5
          *-disk
               description: SCSI Disk
               product: LOGICAL VOLUME
               vendor: HP
               physical id: 0.0.0
               bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
               logical name: /dev/sda
               version: 5.12
               serial: 500143801031E8B0
               size: 136GiB (146GB)
               capabilities: 15000rpm partitioned partitioned:dos
               configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=0007010a
             *-volume:0
                  description: EXT3 volume
                  vendor: Linux
                  physical id: 1
                  bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
                  logical name: /dev/sda1
                  logical name: /boot
                  version: 1.0
                  serial: ed2d10ca-365a-4442-88de-b505aae07eaa
                  size: 102MiB
                  capacity: 102MiB
                  capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes ext3 ext2 initialized
                  configuration: created=2014-11-20 03:17:39 filesystem=ext3 modified=2015-03-15 12:07:09 mount.fstype=ext3 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2015-03-02 08:47:09 state=mounted
             *-volume:1
                  description: EXT3 volume
                  vendor: Linux
                  physical id: 2
                  bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,2
                  logical name: /dev/sda2
                  logical name: /
                  version: 1.0
                  serial: 06719133-4959-4d5d-a288-7d9c00951721
                  size: 20GiB
                  capacity: 20GiB
                  capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files recover ext3 ext2 initialized
                  configuration: created=2014-11-20 03:17:40 filesystem=ext3 modified=2014-11-20 03:23:58 mount.fstype=ext3 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2015-03-15 12:13:47 state=mounted
             *-volume:2
                  description: Linux swap volume
                  physical id: 3
                  bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,3
                  logical name: /dev/sda3
                  version: 1
                  serial: 61605a39-70a7-4121-9cca-49d5bea970ac
                  size: 12GiB
                  capacity: 12GiB
                  capabilities: primary nofs swap initialized
                  configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
             *-volume:3
                  description: Extended partition
                  physical id: 4
                  bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,4
                  logical name: /dev/sda4
                  size: 104GiB
                  capacity: 104GiB
                  capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                *-logicalvolume
                     description: Linux filesystem partition
                     physical id: 5
                     logical name: /dev/sda5
                     logical name: /export/home
                     capacity: 104GiB
                     configuration: mount.fstype=ext3 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered state=mounted
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
         vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
         physical id: 11
         bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
         version: 00
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
         resources: irq:16 ioport:1000(size=8) ioport:1008(size=4) ioport:1010(size=8) ioport:1018(size=4) ioport:1020(size=16) memory:f38f0000-f38f03ff
```

2. (slower)

> 

```
    *-storage
>                 description: RAID bus controller
>                 product: Smart Array G6 controllers
>                 vendor: Hewlett-Packard Company
>                 physical id: 0
>                 bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
>                 logical name: scsi3
>                 version: 01
>                 width: 64 bits
>                 clock: 33MHz
>                 capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom
>                 configuration: driver=hpsa latency=0
>                 resources: irq:40 memory:f3e00000-f3ffffff memory:f3df0000-f3df0fff ioport:4000(size=256)
> memory:f0500000-f057ffff(prefetchable)
>               *-generic UNCLAIMED
>                    description: SCSI
>                    product: P410i
>                    vendor: HP
>                    physical id: 3.0.0
>                    bus info: scsi@3:3.0.0
>                    version: 5.14
>                    serial: 50014380189B2590
>                    configuration: ansiversion=5
>               *-disk
>                    description: SCSI Disk
>                    product: LOGICAL VOLUME
>                    vendor: HP
>                    physical id: 0.0.0
>                    bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
>                    logical name: /dev/sda
>                    version: 5.14
>                    serial: 50014380189B2590
>                    size: 136GiB (146GB)
>                    capabilities: 15000rpm partitioned partitioned:dos
>                    configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=00066463
>                  *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
>                       description: EXT3 volume
>                       vendor: Linux
>                       physical id: 1
>                       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,1
>                       version: 1.0
>                       serial: 8ed9f5e7-ad76-4856-bd71-739fa801c250
>                       size: 102MiB
>                       capacity: 102MiB
>                       capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes recover ext3 ext2 initialized
>                       configuration: created=2013-11-14 19:24:52 filesystem=ext3 modified=2015-02-18 02:37:00 mounted=2015-02-18
> 02:37:00 state=clean
>                  *-volume:1 UNCLAIMED
>                       description: EXT3 volume
>                       vendor: Linux
>                       physical id: 2
>                       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,2
>                       version: 1.0
>                       serial: e0ec5ade-1a3a-4a6f-899b-6dd14e628f63
>                       size: 20GiB
>                       capacity: 20GiB
>                       capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files recover ext3 ext2 initialized
>                       configuration: created=2013-11-14 19:24:53 filesystem=ext3 modified=2013-11-14 19:31:09 mounted=2015-03-07
> 17:39:26 state=clean
>                  *-volume:2 UNCLAIMED
>                       description: Linux swap volume
>                       physical id: 3
>                       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,3
>                       version: 1
>                       serial: 269a2358-bd61-4d39-8a56-7354ebb03f76
>                       size: 12GiB
>                       capacity: 12GiB
>                       capabilities: primary nofs swap initialized
>                       configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4096
>                  *-volume:3 UNCLAIMED
>                       description: Extended partition
>                       physical id: 4
>                       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0,4
>                       size: 104GiB
>                       capacity: 104GiB
>                       capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
>                     *-logicalvolume UNCLAIMED
>                          description: Linux filesystem partition
>                          physical id: 5
>                          capacity: 104GiB
>         *-storage
>              description: SATA controller
>              product: SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode]
>              vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
>              physical id: 11
>              bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
>              version: 00
>              width: 32 bits
>              clock: 66MHz
>              capabilities: storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
>              configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
>              resources: irq:16 ioport:1000(size=8) ioport:1008(size=4) ioport:1010(size=8) ioport:1018(size=4) ioport:1020(size=16)
> memory:f38f0000-f38f03ff
```

Comment: Did you investigate why the volumes in the second listing are all unclaimed? Perhaps due to the version difference?

Comment: can you tell me, please, why this is important, what does it mean? thanks.

Comment: The site http://www.ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter#Howtointerpretlshwsoutput states that: "a node is marked as UNCLAIMED if no specific support for it has been loaded (or lshw has been unable to identify the driver).". If there is no specific or correct driver loaded it may impact the performance.

Comment: Very interesting. We are going to check that. Thank you very much!